# SSH to remote server using identity key in another

Tags: ssh, netcat, ssh-tunnel, x11-forwarding

I am in server A.I want to ssh to server C via B.
I have access to
1.ssh directly to B using identity keys.
2.B needs to generate a key using which it can access C.

I need a command to login to C from A , to include the key generation in B and using the same to login to C.

```
ssh -o 'ProxyCommand ssh  -i <key in A> <B> nc %h 22'  <C>
```

The above tunnel works if there is no key-based authentication from B to C.

Unable to incorporate the key generation and using the same. Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -o 'ProxyCommand ssh  -i <key in A> <B> nc %h 22'  <C>
```

authenticates you to the host C using the keys on the host A.

Comment: Unfortunately , my key for ssh to C , is in B.

Comment: Then copy them back to local computer or use `ssh B ssh C` way

Comment: I cannot copy the key , because of security reasons.What is "ssh B ssh C way " ?Could you please explain?Will I be able to scp using the same?

Comment: Then just do `ssh B ssh C`. It is not elegant, but it works.

Comment: Yes.Thanks.I am able to do it. Just one question..is scp possible with the same?

Comment: No. For scp, you would have to do two scp commands, one from A to B, the second from B to C.

Comment: A-B is a straight method .But how should I do from B to C ?Could you please give me an example? I am not getting it due to the key involved .

Comment: just connect to the server B using ssh and scp the file from B to C.